# Loop until end of document

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I need to select every third line of a document and format the text to bold, underlined, and blue.  I already have the code for this, but I need to loop it for a set number of times.

The problem is, all of the looping tutorials I find use variables or state to do this until some condition is met.  How can I set that condition to be "reached the bottom of the document?"

The code I set up is below, and the bracketed lines are what I need help with:

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

[Do the following code until the end of the document]

        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        With Selection.Font
            .Bold = wdToggle
            .Color = 12611584
            .Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        End With

        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=3

[end of loop]
```

Very basic question.  I am familiar with setting these types of loops in excel, but in word, I can't figure it out. I appreciate anyone who takes the time to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number Of Lines")
MsgBox lastRow
```

[BuiltInDocumentProperties KB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197172.aspx)

So something like this would work and be the same type of `for` loop as excel -

```
Sub CountLines()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
lastRow = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number Of Lines")
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
        'Do Stuff
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Or to be more thorough -

```
Sub CountLines()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    lastRow = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number Of Lines")
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
            ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Font.Bold = True
            'Do other stuff
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```